# How to set divs in 2x2 table to equal height of tallest div in row?

Tags: css

I have a div containing four divs in a 2x2 formation, each of which contain a different block of text, each of varying length. I want to define the CSS so that the shortest div on the top row is equal to its neighbour on that row, and the same for the divs along the bottom row. Is there a way to achieve this using CSS? My current CSS properties are as follows:

```
.container{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.container > div{
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    width: 49%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: If you always know what the shortest div is, then you can use the `CSS` property `calc()`  -- If you don't know which the shortest div is, you may considering using `JavaScript` to look at the two `divs`, **compare** their heights, and **set** the shortest one **equal** to the tallest one.

Comment: The `display` setting for `.container > div` should be `table-cell`, and you better also use rows as a layer between table and cells. If you want to *nest*  smaller tables in the cells, do that with another child element.

Comment: Conversely if you were to use a framework such as [BootStrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) this would all be handled for you between the use of rows and columns.

Answer (score -2):

In jquery you can get the height of the first one then set the 2nd to that.  In css you can pick a static number 100px... height:100px, width:auto maybe